# ps3 trophy calculator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I decided to do a windows phone 7 ps3 trophy calc app..the point breakdown is following

- Bronze Trophies are worth: 15 Points
- Silver Trophies are worth: 30 Points
- Gold Trophies are worth: 90 Points
- Platinum Trophies are worth: 180 Points

Each level breakdown is

- Level 2 is at 200 Points
- Level 3 is at 600 Points
- Level 4 is at 1200 Points
- Level 5 is at 2400 Points
- Level 6 is at 4000 Points

After that is rises by 2000 for each level till level 12 at 16000 points
At level 13 it goes to 24000 and it increases by 8000 with each succeeding level.

I am able to determine the level till level 12... I have problems determining level if point > =16000 ...can u explain me the logic to determine level for point>16000 ??? the level cap after level 12 is a constant 8000....

Comment: Post the code that is not working and we can help you.

Comment: The question is kind of off-topic. You should ask it in the programmer's or math sites…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, it would be something like

```
int levelCap = (8000 * (level % 12)) + 16000;
```

Please note that this logic will only work if you are level 12 or over

Comment: i want to find the level... so if the point is 32,000 , how will i find the level??

Answer (score 0):

This is a very nested loop, so that if the points are only enough for level 2, it checks level 3, and when it sees it as false it escapes the entire thing.

```
int const level = 1;
int const level2 = 200;
int const level6 = 4000;
int const level12 = 16000;

if (points >= level2)
    level = 2;
    if (points >= 3*level2)
        level = 3;
        if (points >= 6*level2)
           level = 4;
           if (points >= 12*level2)
                level = 5;
                if ((points >= level6) && (points < level12))
                    // because you're dividing integer by integer,
                    // 39999/2000 should = 1, correct?
                    level = ((points - level6) / 2000) + 6;
                else if (points >= level12)
                    level = ((points - level12 / 8000) + 12;
```

Comment: @wishper Why wouldn't you want level2 6 and 12 as constants? they're not dynamic...

Comment: Hummmm .. that's curious. I didn't want to change the code, just reformat it. I don't understant how and why the `const` have been removed. And you're right, they should be constants.